# Sublime Text 3 Newly opened file override existing file

Tags: sublimetext3

Say I have `/doc/index.html` opened in ST3, when I open another file like `/src/foo.html` or `/foo/index.html/` , the newly opened file override the existing file `/doc/index.html` !  That is, the existing file just disappear and is substituted by the newly opened file.  How can I solve that?

Comment: EDIT: [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29770727/3870761). Thank you.