# Can't open in new tab in Sublime Text 3. Is it a bug?

Tags: tabs, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Today my Sublime 3083 became corrupted! I don't know why but every time I click on a file it opens on the same tab!
I cannot open two tabs at the same time. Fist file opens in a new tab and another opens in the previous tab and so on!

I did not installed any plugins recently. I just selected "Close Other Tabs" on menu.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening the files using double click instead of single click?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Double Click works :) Please add an answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**You must open the file using double click.** If you open it using single click then you're using a feature called *file preview*, and that file will be closed when you preview other file unless the file has changes.

---

In addition, in the settings file you can set the `preview_on_click` option to `false` to disable the preview option; if you do that a click on the file won't do nothing, and a double click will still open the file in a new tab. As far as I know there's no option to open the file with a single click, only you can 'preview' the file (it's similar to open but the file get closed if you preview another file). Example setting:

```
{
    "preview_on_click": false
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,i been googling this for long and all crazy stuff came up.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar but little different problem. I was not able to view any tabs I was opening, and it was always opening a new file.

I fixed it by "View" -> "Show Tabs".